# Angles between planes in 4D

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two intersecting two dimensional planes in a four dimensional Euclidean space. It seems to me that there are two angles between these planes. If the two planes intersect in a line then one of those angles is zero. If the two angles are non-zero then the planes intersect in a point. If one plane is the $wx$ plane and the other the $yz$ plane then the two angles are both 90 degrees.

The best I can do is this. Each plane is defined by two orthonormal basis vectors. Project a basis vector onto the other plane. Then the angle is the $\arccos$ of the length of the projection. Do this with each basis vector to get the two angles. However I believe that the result depends on the choice of basis vectors.

What I need could be to find a unit vector in a plane so that it's projection onto the other plane is of maximum length.  I don't know how to do that.  I suppose find an expression for the length, take the derivative, and find where it is zero.

Comment: Already asked by the OP on MSE as [Finding angles between planes in 4D space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487760/finding-angles-between-planes-in-4d-space).

Comment: @dxiv Oops! Next time I'll remember to do a dupe search before voting to migrate...

Comment: @PM2Ring No worry, the end result will likely be the same i.e. one copy of the question remaining. That said, it's a good idea for posters to link their cross-posts themselves, for more reasons than one.